# ASP.NET deploy package created only when building from the command line

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, msbuild

I have an ASP.NET MVC project whose project file I modified to have the following properties so that it would create a deploy package in a subdirectory of the output folder when it builds in the Release configuration:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <DeployTarget>Package</DeployTarget>
    <DeployOnBuild>true</DeployOnBuild>
    <CreatePackageOnPublish>true</CreatePackageOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When I build the project from the command line as follows:

```
msbuild projectname.csproj /p:Configuration=Release
```

Then, the deploy files are packaged up correctly in a subdirectory underneath the Release output. However, if I build the project from within Visual Studio the deploy files and packages aren't created, even if I have the configuration set to Release.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are not under the any CPU playpen in vs?  You could probably remove that all together from the conditional.

Comment: Good call, but unfortunately, I was in the Any CPU platform. Just to be sure I removed that from the property group conditional and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried it with no conditional at all?  An eliminating possible causes step